# reverse a segment of array starting from index i to j (inclusive)

Tags: java, arrays

I want to reverse a part of a given array starting from index i till j (both inclusive). For example if it contains:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

After reverse process it should look like this:

```
1 6 5 4 3 2 7
```

in this case i=1, j=5.
My method is:

```
  public static void sw(int[] l, int i,int j)
  {
    for(int z=i; z<((j-i)+1)/2;z++)
    {
      int y=((j-i)+1) - z - 1;
      int temp = l[z];
      l[z] = l[y];
      l[y] = temp;
    }
  }
```

It is not working fine for some cases.

```
Case#1:

6 78 63 59 28 24 8 96 99
output is:
6 78 59 63 28 24 8 96 99
```

Comment: Please define the input for "some cases" and what it outputs.

Comment: And what cases specifically is it not working for? In what way is it not working? How does your output vary from your expected output?

Comment: Try to take smaller input, like 1 2 3 4 5 and "run" it manually. You'll learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove 'z' and 'y' completely. They're too complex and unnecessary to accomplish the task. You merely want to increment 'i' and decrement 'j' until `i <= j`
is no longer true.

Thus we have:

```
public static void sw(int[] l, int i,int j)
  {
    for(; i<=j;i++, j--)
    {
      int temp = l[i];
      l[i] = l[j];
      l[j] = temp;
    }
  }
```

The for loop has an empty first statement, as 'i' has already been declared.

Hope this helps!